# Ordered doubly-linked lock-free list

Tags: c, linked-list, linux, lock-free

I'm implementing a lock-free ordered doubly-linked list based on heavily modified paper entitled [*Split-Ordered Lists: Lock-Free Extensible Hash Tables* by ORI SHALEV](http://people.csail.mit.edu/shanir/publications/Split-Ordered_Lists.pdf). My main concern is correctness of algorithm, secondly performance.

Is the algorithm used in the code really lock-free? How can I improve the code?

```
typedef __uint64_t              uint64_t;
typedef uintptr_t               node_ptr_t;
#define PTR_OF(x)               ((Node*)(x))
#define CONSTRUCT(ptr)          ((uintptr_t)ptr)
#define CAS(ADDR, OLDV, NEWV)   __sync_val_compare_and_swap((ADDR), (OLDV), (NEWV))
#define INCR(ADDR, INCVAL)      __sync_fetch_and_add((ADDR), (INCVAL))

typedef struct
{
    int             mark;
    void            *value;
    uint64_t        key;
    node_ptr_t      prev, next;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    node_ptr_t      bucket;
    uint32_t        size;
} LF_List;

void* lf_list_find(LF_List* list, node_ptr_t* head, uint64_t key, node_ptr_t** prev, node_ptr_t* cur, node_ptr_t* last)
{
    node_ptr_t*     tp_prev;
    node_ptr_t      tp_cur, tp_last;
    node_ptr_t*     tp_next;

    uint64_t cur_key;
    void* cur_value;

    while(1)
    {
        tp_prev = head;
        tp_cur  = *head;
        tp_last = (node_ptr_t)NULL;

        while(1)
        {
            if (PTR_OF(tp_cur) == NULL)
            {
                if(prev){*prev = tp_prev;};
                if(cur){*cur = tp_cur;};
                if(last){*last = tp_last;};

                return NULL;
            }

            tp_next = &PTR_OF(tp_cur)->next;

            cur_key = PTR_OF(tp_cur)->key;
            cur_value = PTR_OF(tp_cur)->value;

            if(*tp_prev != tp_cur)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (PTR_OF(tp_cur)->mark == 1)
            {

                if (PTR_OF(*tp_next) != NULL)
                {
                    if (CAS(&PTR_OF(*tp_next)->prev, tp_cur, tp_last) != tp_cur)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (CAS(tp_prev, tp_cur, *tp_next) == tp_cur) {

                    free(PTR_OF(tp_cur));
                    tp_cur = *tp_next;
                    INCR(&list->size, -1);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }           
            } else if (CAS(&PTR_OF(tp_cur)->mark, 2, 0) == 2)
            {
                if (PTR_OF(*tp_next) != NULL)
                {
                    if (CAS(&PTR_OF(*tp_next)->prev, tp_last, tp_cur) == tp_last)
                    {
                        INCR(&list->size, 1);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (key >= cur_key)
            {
                if(prev){*prev = tp_prev;};
                if(cur){*cur = tp_cur;};
                if(last){*last = tp_last;};

                return key == cur_key ? cur_value : NULL;
            }

            tp_last = tp_cur;
            tp_prev = tp_next;
            tp_cur = *tp_next;
        }
    }
}

void* lf_list_get(LF_List* list, uint64_t key)
{
    return lf_list_find(list, &list->bucket, key, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

void* lf_list_put_if_absent(LF_List* list, uint64_t key, void* value)
{
    node_ptr_t* prev;
    node_ptr_t cur, last;
    node_ptr_t new_node;

    while(1)
    {
        if(lf_list_find(list, &list->bucket, key, &prev, &cur, &last) != NULL)
        {
            return PTR_OF(cur)->value;
        }

        new_node = CONSTRUCT(calloc(1, sizeof(Node)));

        PTR_OF(new_node)->value = value;
        PTR_OF(new_node)->key = key;
        PTR_OF(new_node)->mark = 2;

        PTR_OF(new_node)->next = *prev;
        PTR_OF(new_node)->prev = last;

        if(CAS(prev, cur, new_node) == cur)
        {
            lf_list_find(list, &last, key, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        } else {
            free(PTR_OF(new_node));
            continue;
        }       
    }
    return NULL;
}

int lf_list_remove(LF_List* list, uint64_t key)
{
    node_ptr_t cur, last;
    node_ptr_t *prev;

    if(lf_list_find(list, &list->bucket, key, &prev, &cur, &last) == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    PTR_OF(cur)->mark = 1;

    lf_list_find(list, &last, key, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Still not safe

I haven't run the new code yet but I can already theorize at least one possible flaw.  Suppose you have the following list:

`4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1`

Then suppose element 2 is deleted:

`4 -> 3 -> 2* -> 1     (* = marked for deletion)`

Now thread 1 iterates across the list and stops at element 2, and is about to delete it.  Meanwhile, element 3 is deleted:

`4 -> 3* -> 2* -> 1`

Thread 2 iterates across the list and stops at element 3.  Now you have two threads both trying to delete separate elements at the same time.  One is trying to make `4` point to `2`.  The other is trying to make `3` point to `1`.  All sorts of bad things can happen.  I'm even leaving out the part where the list is now doubly linked with `prev` pointers.

The reason that the research paper algorithm works is because the `mark` is stored within the `next` pointer.  That way, the `CAS` will fail if it tries to change the pointer with the wrong mark on it.  With your program, the `mark` is stored separately from the `next` pointer.  Therefore, you can't atomically change both the mark and the pointer.